# CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync not recognising enum

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync` to generate a predicate from a string.  Using string and int variables it works fine but if I try to pass in an enum variable in the string to convert it throws the error:

> Message   "(1,26): error CS0103: The name 'Status' does not exist in the current context" string

Here is the standalone reproduction:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

namespace PredicateParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var albums = new List<Album>
            {
                new Album { Quantity = 10, Artist = "Betontod", Title = "Revolution", Status = Status.Offline},
                new Album { Quantity = 50, Artist = "The Dangerous Summer", Title = "The Dangerous Summer", Status = Status.Offline },
                new Album { Quantity = 200, Artist = "Depeche Mode", Title = "Spirit", Status = Status.Online },
            };


            var albumFilter1 = "album => album.Quantity > 20 && album.Quantity < 200"; //works fine
            var albumFilter2 = "album => album.Status == Status.Online"; //Throws exception

            var predicate1 = CreatePredicate<Album>(albumFilter1);
            var predicate2 = CreatePredicate<Album>(albumFilter2);

            var filteredAlbums1 = albums.Where(predicate1).ToList();
            var filteredAlbums2 = albums.Where(predicate2).ToList();

        }

        public static Func<T, bool> CreatePredicate<T>(string command)
        {
            var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(T).Assembly);
            Func<T, bool> predicate = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<T, bool>>(command, options).Result;

            return predicate;
        }

    }



    public class Album
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        Online,
        Offline
    }
    
}
```

How can I get it to work with enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(T).Assembly).AddImports(nameof(PredicateParser));
```

You forgot to add "using namespace" :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there's no error if you fully qualify it with the namespace.

```
"album => album.Status == PredicateParser.Status.Online"
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while I was working on a dynamic filtering feature (*I had to build an expression for the `.Where(...)` calls*) when a filtering property was an `Enum` type.

I had to change my lambda **from**

❌ `"t => t.IntervalType == Enum.Parse<IntervalType>("Cron")"`

**to this**

✅ `"t => t.IntervalType == System.Enum.Parse<TaskScheduler.Core.Models.IntervalType>("Cron")"`.

To build the lambda, I was using string interpolation for values in this form

❌ `$"Enum.Parse<{t.Name}>(\"{value}\")"`

that had to be updated to this:

✅ `$"System.Enum.Parse<{t.FullName}>(\"{value}\")"`